# Orthogonality of a domain and image of an operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let A be an unbounded operator in a complex Hilbert space. $A: D(A)\subsetneq \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}(A)$.

Could one have $D(A)^{\perp} = \mathcal{R}(A)$? Or is this not true for any unbounded operator in a complex Hilbert space?

Comment: Let $D(A)$ be any dense subspace and let $A=0$.  Or did you want $A$ to be closed?

Comment: Or in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $D(A)$ be the $x$-axis and let $A$ be rotation by 90 degrees.

Comment: No, A must not be the $0$ operator.

Comment: So then $D(A)$ can't be dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_0$ be some infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and let $A_0 : D(A_0) \subset H_0 \to H_0$ be your favorite unbounded surjective operator.  You may even take $A_0$ to be closed and densely defined, e.g. take $H_0 = \ell^2$ realized as a space of functions from $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, $D(A_0) = \{x \in \ell^2 : \sum_n n^2 |x(n)|^2 < \infty\}$ and $(A_0 x)(n) = n x(n)$.

Now let $H = H_0 \oplus H_0$, $D(A) = D(A_0) \oplus 0$, and $A(x,y) = (0, A_0 x)$.  Then $A$ is closed and unbounded, and $D(A)^\perp = R(A) = 0 \oplus H_0$.

Comment: Sorry to comeback to this. Let me rephrase this as: let A be unbounded without any other further restriction. Does $\langle x, Ax\rangle = 0, \forall x\in D(A) $ mean that $A=0$, or, in order for A to be $0$, A must be at least densely defined, or possibly even closed? Thanks!

Comment: @DanielC: This is not true and has nothing to do with unboundedness.  Think about $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the (closed, bounded, everywhere defined) operator $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.

Comment: Ok, but if A is hermitean (symmetric), then A is 0, right?

Comment: @DanielC: Yes, if $A$ is a densely defined symmetric operator, then $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in D(A)$ implies $A=0$.  This is a standard exercise. Densely defined is still necessary, essentially by the example I gave in my earlier comment: consider $H = \mathbb{C}^2$ with orthonormal basis $\{e_1, e_2\}$, let $D(A)$ be the span of $e_1$ and let $A e_1 = e_2$.  Then $A$ is trivially symmetric and satisfies the desired condition but is not zero.